# Modify or decorate a bezier / curve

Tags: bezier-curves

Is there a simple way to "modify" / "decorate" a bezier / curve (==curve in the following). For example:

- modify a curve so that it is dashed or dotted;
- decorate a curve so that it has something (an arrow tip, could be a curve or a mesh) at its end (or somewhere else: at its beginning or in its middle).

Obviously, I can add a decoration (an arrow) as an object, grad it and attach it to the curve. I can use an array modifier and simulate a dashed pattern. But that's not what I'm looking for. I'd like this to act like a modifier.

Comment: Motivation: As a physics teacher, I'd like to easily draw e.g. vectors (say the electromagnetic field).

Comment: you can do at least something about this "decoration" using the freestyle post processing https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/introduction.html#what-is-freestyle (which generates 2d lines/outlines related to the 3d scene, and can also be exported to svg with a bundled addon - disabled by default)